# Calculo con seno y coseno

Tags: c++

me surge un problema a la hora de operar con la libreria #math.h en C++. Cuando opero con el seno o el coseno, su resultado es en radianes y me interesa que dicho valor sea en sexagesimal.

¿Hay alguna manera de transferir el valor o implementar el mismo numero pi?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira te muestro la forma en la que lo puedes hacer... Como obtienes los grados en **radianes** lo primero es llevarlo a **decimal** por tanto usarias esta formula

> **grados = rad * 180/π**

Luego sigues estos pasos(el ejemplo es con el grado **121.135°**

1. La parte entera de los grados decimales será también los grados del sistema sexagesimal (121°).
2. Multiplicar los decimales del valor original por 60 (.135 * 60 = 8.1).
3. La parte entera del resultado anterior serán los minutos (8’).
4. Multiplicar los decimales del paso 2 por 60 (.1 * 60 = 6).
5. El resultado del paso anterior serán los segundos (6’’).
6. Tomar los resultados de los pasos 1, 3 y 5 para formar el resultado final (121°8’6’’).

Y asi obtienes de radian a sexagesimal...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double grados;
    cin >> grados;

    double result = sin(grados) * 180 / M_PI;

    string sexagesimal;

    int parteEntera = result;

    double parteFracc = result - (int)parteEntera;

    parteFracc*=60;

    int minutos = parteFracc;

    int sec = (parteFracc - (int)minutos) * 60;

    cout << parteEntera << "grados" <<  minutos <<  '\'' <<  sec << '\"';

    return 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo supon que resultado da 121.135 grados entonces pasaria exactamente lo descrito en los pasos.

Comment: Cual sería la respuesta en C++? , te sugiero revisar [answer] y agregar esta información que es la se pregunta, si la pregunta no es clara lo mejor es ayudar al OP a editar su pregunta y requerir agregue más información.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya agregue el codigo no pense que fuera necesario por eso no lo puse...